# input:text Alert Parent Class?

Tags: jquery

My hover target is "#Font-Size input:text" of which in in my HTML code as seen below;

```
<div id="Font-Type">
    <input type="text" name="Size-Input" maxlength="2" value="12">
```

Upon hovering over my text input field, I would like JQuery to open up an alert box with it's parent ID of "#Font-Type". I've tried the following, but even without the ".parent()" section, the alert box just shows "OBJECT";

```
var thisParent = $(this).parent();
alert(thisParent);
```

Has anyone got any ideas as I'm trying to minimize the code required for my page as there'll be more than one "input:text" of which I'll need to find the parent for.

Best Regards,

Tim

Comment: The best idea ever would be to start using the console for debugging, and not alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
alert($(thisParent).attr("id"));
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jurgenstillaert/ySMLE/

thisParent is an DOM object, you can address its properties and event handlers by using the $() handle.

Comment: Thank you for your input, +1 for a working solution and awarded for your extra effort providing a JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing object to alert instead of some string i.e id in your case. You need to use `attr()` to show `id`

```
alert(thisParent.attr("id"));
```

or

```
alert(thisParent[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var thisParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
alert(thisParent);
```

Answer (score 0):

alert show you object because `$(this)` contain DOM object.

If you want to alert ID then use it as below.

```
alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var thisParent = $(this).parent();
alert(thisParent.attr('id'));
```

When you do this:

```
var thisParent = $(this).parent();
alert(thisParent);
```

This gives you the `parent` jQuery object and that's why you get an alert like "OBJECT";

In order to get the `id` in jQuery, we need to do like this:

```
$(element).attr('id');
```

This would return you the jQuery object `id` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your input, +1 for a working solution, if I could award two, I would award your answer as well, however I received 7 answers so fast and all seem to be good and working!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code : Also make sure your div is properly closed.

```
  alert(thisParent.attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
$("#txt").hover(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));    
 }); 
});
```